# Download file from http response, using reactJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, google-chrome, extjs

I have a code like this:

```
getZipFile(){
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "http://localhost:8081/myAppName/protected/upload/download.do",
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        entityId: this.props.currentEntityId
    },
    jsonData: litOfDocumentsIdINeed,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
      //
      //  I have what I need at this point, it is inside of 'records'
      //  the problem is here: I get the document in records, but I need
      //  to Download it automatically, as soon as I receive these records
      //  But HOW?
      //
    }
  })
}
```

So, I receive that file, that's good, but how to go step further and to automatically download it?

Comment: You dont have to write any code specially to download any file. This is part of response which browser get and according to it any resource is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this after getting the callback response -

```
var filename = 'test' //set the file name here
var blob = new Blob([records], { type: 'add file type here' });
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = filename;

document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();

document.body.removeChild(link);
```